# How do I fix the position of my flex box images?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im having issues with aligning my 6 images in 2 rows of 3.  - 1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
At the moment they are in 3 rows. The first 2 images are in the centre of the page, while the others are all on the 3rd line. Not sure if its an issue with the div tags or the css. Im using flexbox at the moment but I know theres also grid layout

Please can you advise? Thanks very much

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160%;
  height: 300px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 90px;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}

.rounded {
  border-radius: 20%;
}

button {
  border-radius: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>

  </head>
  <header>


    <nav>
      <button><a href="/Volumes/Untitled/coding/Cart.html" class="rounded">Go to 
    Cart</a></button>

      <button><a href="/Volumes/Untitled/codingShop.html" class="rounded">Shop</a></button>
      <ul>
        <img src="images/Logo2.jpeg" alt="my logo" class="rounded" width="160px" />

        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
  </header>
  <h3>
    Welcome to Luminous Butter. We dont sell Butter we do sell vintage, Customised and pre-loved Fashion Original Artwork Plus, we have a great blog which has original stories and writing to keep you entertained
  </h3>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="images/Fred.jpeg" alt="accessories" class="rounded" width="280px">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="images/BlackonBlack.jpg" alt="photography" class="rounded" width="500px">
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="images/Boy.jpeg" alt="fashion" class="rounded" width="300px">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="images/Campbell.jpeg" alt="footwear" class="rounded" width="400px">
          </div>

          <div class="container">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="images/Scandal.jpeg" alt="jewellery" class="rounded" width="300px">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="images/bowie-big.jpeg" alt="art" class="rounded" width="300px">
              </div>


            </div>
```

Comment: You're starting with invalid HTML, no element other than an `<li>` can appear inside of a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`). Also, you seem to be nesting `.container` elements, which doesn't look intentional, but a typo. Please correct your HTML, and then we can start looking at, and working with, your CSS.

Comment: I didnt copy the html part. Thanks for the info on the ul. Can you explain the nesting container part further please?

Comment: You have many `.container` elements. You open one, then you open a `.image` element. In there you have an `<img>`, and then you close the `.image`. You then open another `.container`. So the third `.container` is inside the second `.container`, which is inside the first `.container`. I imagine they're meant to be siblings, rather than descendants.

Comment: so, 2 containers, rather than 6? thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your `a` inside your button. Also, as mentioned in the comments you cannot have an `img` as a direct child to a `ul` that is not nested in a `li`. So I nested it in a `li` and removed the default `padding-inline-start` to keep the same structure. Then I went down to your rows and simplified it so it is two rows of 3 as requested. Please see how I simplified the rows below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160%;
  height: 300px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 90px;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}

.rounded {
  border-radius: 20%;
}

button {
  border-radius: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <button><a href="/Volumes/Untitled/coding/Cart.html" class="rounded">Go to Cart</a></button>
    <button><a href="/Volumes/Untitled/codingShop.html" class="rounded">Shop</a></button>
    <ul>
      <li style="padding: 0;">
        <a href="/"><img src="logo.png" alt="my logo" class="rounded" width="160px"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<h3>
  Welcome to Luminous Butter. We dont sell Butter we do sell vintage, Customised and pre-loved Fashion Original Artwork Plus, we have a great blog which has original stories and writing to keep you entertained
</h3>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="accessories" class="rounded" width="280px">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="photography" class="rounded" width="500px">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="fashion" class="rounded" width="300px">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="footwear" class="rounded" width="300px">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="jewellery" class="rounded" width="300px">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="art" class="rounded" width="300px">
</div>
```

Comment: this makes sense, and thank you for the extra help on my other errors